# twython error "cannot immport name 'Tywthon'"

Tags: python

Any help would be much appreciated as it is wrecking my head many thanks

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

 t = Twython(
     'l7YjRZwEhMe9qwFuWBPsilFjs'
     '3JEkKl88fkq20jyDr8UTY1C5PPNlTdR54lfQbAGSk2IjDnCA10'
 )

 reulsts = t.search(q="#liverpool", count = 3)
 all_tweets = results ['statuses']

for tweet in all_tweets:
print(tweet['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install it first with:

```
pip install twython
```

Or with easy_install:

```
easy_install twython
```

Comment: i restarted IPython and still a no go

Comment: Maybe you have 2 distributions of python? Do you use the correct python?

Comment: what do you suggest to use ?

Comment: What do you mean? `Python 2` or `Python 3`?

Comment: i just unistalled python and downloaded Anaconda and now its working messed up stuff ha thanks for your help pal